# Concatenate characters of string values to the same column values

Tags: python, pandas, list

Please I need help with string characters. I have a Data frame with one columns having the following values:

```
df['m2'] =  ['98', '100x107','86x90', '85', '90x100','124x148', '95']
```

I would like to concatenate 'x(number)' to those  values that are just a single number. having this result:

```
 df['m2'] =  ['98x98', '100x107','86x90', '85x85', '90x100','124x148', '95x95']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a list comprehension:

```
df['m2'] = [f'{e}x{e}' if 'x' not in e else e for e in df['m2']]
df
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

```
m = ~df.m2.str.contains('x')
df.loc[m, 'm2'] += 'x' + df.loc[m, 'm2']
```

---

```
        m2
0    98x98
1  100x107
2    86x90
3    85x85
4   90x100
5  124x148
6    95x95
```